# Sql Server compact toolbox in VS 2013

Tags: sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-toolbox

I installed VS 2013 ultimate and Sql server compact 3.7.2 ,I opened my project but It seems that the SQlCe 3.5 link is grayed out and I can not open it and the other link of opening solution database causes an error and crashes VS .

[image: SQl server Compact]

[image: Sql server compact About]

[image: Registry]

I do not want to change DB to version 4.0 ,Could you please help me opening the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 runtime MSI(s)

Comment: Then repair/reinstall, check the about dialog in the Toolbox to verify that your install is broken

Comment: Yes, so repair/reinstall, as I said.. Did you upgrade from Windows 8 to 8.1?

Comment: Yes I did repair and uninstall/reinstall SqlCe toolkit but no change, No I Installed new copy of windows 8.1 last week.

Comment: Did you re-install the SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 runtime MSIs? Not the Toolbox!

Comment: Sorry I was not clear , I did repaired SQl server compact 3.5 SP2 and unistalled the toolkit and then reinstalled the toolkit and then I checked the registery according to your blog .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54139/discussion-between-ali-haider-and-erikej).